# Why do we care about non-$T_0$ spaces?

Tags: general-topology, motivation

(Reminder: A $T_0$ topological space, also known as a [Kolmogorov space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space), is a space where the topological structure "recognizes" that [different points are different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_indistinguishability): No two points have exactly the same open sets around them.)

For a space that is not $T_0$, we can uniquely form a $T_0$ space from it by taking the [Kolmogorov quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_quotient), which just means sending two points to the same point in the quotient iff they are, so to speak, a counterexample to $T_0$-ness. This induces an isomorphism (i.e. order-preserving, union-/finite intersection-compatible bijection) on the topologies of the old space and the new space<s>, and the new space is homeomorphic to any other $T_0$ space with the same topology</s>.

Wikipedia seems to say that we can toggle $T_0$-ness on and off and get analogous theorems in many cases. But it also says, "[...] it may also be easier to allow structures that aren't T0 to get a fuller picture."

In short, I'm wondering:

- What does point-set topology lose if we require topological spaces to always be $T_0$? (Probably nothing, in pure point-set topology.)
- What non-$T_0$ spaces in other fields have desirable properties that are lost on Kolmogorov quotient?

(P.S.: I admit that I've been thinking about pointless topology. There's no tag for it?)

Comment: As I understand, the requirement for moving to pointless topology is not $T_0$, but ["sober"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space). I'm planning to think about that myself, so, uh, please don't spoil it for me (if it's not necessary for an answer to the public).

Comment: Most of the questions you might ask on pointless topology would fit under either order theory/lattice theory or topos theory. Regarding the main question, I don't know an important use for non-$T_0$ spaces. There are very important non-$T_1$ spaces, namely, spectra, so the distinction is either sharp or wrong.

Comment: You are probably right about pure topology. In applied topology, pseudometrics arise naturally, e.g. in function spaces. Of course you can make them metric spaces by taking a quotient, but maybe it's more natural to think of the "points" as functions rather than equivalence classes of functions.

Comment: The coarse topology, and some spaces  that have some infinite subspaces that have the coarse topology, are useful in constructing examples and counter-examples in point-set topology.

Comment: @user254665 Counterexamples aren't something to "care" about. I could instead ask, "What do we lose if we add $T^0$ to the axioms for a topological space?"

Comment: Counter-examples in topology, which are many, are something topologists care about strongly.

Comment: @user254665 I made an entire post up there which elaborates on what I mean by "care", including two alternative questions. "Counterexamples" does not address either. The lack of an interesting property is not, in general, an interesting property in and of itself, but only in contrast. Counterexamples are not, in general, interesting in and of themselves, but only in contrast with an expected conclusion.

Comment: Put another way, T^0 spaces as "counter-examples" are not (universally) interesting spaces. The interesting part for each claim is whether or not counterexamples _exist_ (i.e. whether a particular category of spaces is nonempty).

Comment: Topological spaces over a given set form a lattice by inclusion order. This is not the case for $T_0$ spaces. I don't know how important that is, but it is certainly something you lose if you add $T_0$ as a requirement.

Answer (score 4):

1. Losing the indiscrete topology would be unfortunate in several ways. As celtschk points out in the comments, this is the minimal element in the lattice of topologies ordered by inclusion. Moreover, the indiscrete topology gives us a right-adjoint to the forgetful functor from $Top$ to $Set$.
2. Related to 1.: Given some family of functions $(f_i : X \to Y)_{i \in I}$ and a topology on $Y$, we can construct the initial topology on $X$. If all topologies have to be $T_0$, then we would need to quotient here, which just makes stuff slightly more complicated.
3. We have separation axioms for points and we have separation axioms for sets. Without the $T_0$ requirement, their interaction becomes more complicated. Some people might like to explore this (I personally don't, but taste differs.)
4. Related to 2.: If we care about the particular elements of a space, and only consider the topology as a means to understand them better, then taking quotients is annoying. For example, we might be interested in integrable functions, and care about the identity of functions beyond being equal almost everywhere. Still, the topology induced by the pseudodistance is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a space of genuine interest that is not $\text{T}_0$, and for which the non-$\text{T}_0$ aspects are rich and significant.
The answer is long, in an attempt to be readable.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of all properly convex (i.e. convex and closure contained in an affine chart) open subsets of $\mathbb{RP}^2$. Give $\mathcal{C}$ the Hausdorff topology on closures with respect to a reference metric on $\mathbb{RP}^2$. That is, $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ are close if every point in $\overline{\Omega_1}$ is close to a point of $\overline{\Omega_2}$ and vice versa. The group $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ of matrices acts on $\mathbb{RP}^2$ and sends lines to lines because linear transformations send subspaces to subspaces. It follows that $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ preserves proper convexity, and acts continuously on $\mathcal{C}$. Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be $\mathcal{C}/\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$, equipped with the quotient topology.

$\mathfrak{C}$ is not $\text{T}_0$.
The standard proof $\mathfrak{C}$ is not $\text{T}_1$ by examining matricies of the form $A_t = \text{diag}(e^t, 1, e^{-t})$.
Any such matrix preserves an ellipse $E$, and for large $t$ takes small neighborhoods of a boundary point $p^-$ onto all of $E$ except a small neighborhood of a second boundary point $p^+$. Taking a half-ellipse $C$ containing $p^-$, we then have $[A_t C] = [C]$ for all $t$, but $A_t C$ converges to $E$ in the Hausdorff topology, so that the constant sequence $[C]$ has distinct limit points $[C]$ and $[E]$. Non-$\text{T}_0$-ness is less easy to see.

The non-$\text{T}_0$ structure of $\mathfrak{C}$ is both rich and controlled: there are dense points in $\mathfrak{C}$, while there finite-dimensional families of arbitrarily large dimension of closed points in $\mathfrak{C}$.
On the other hand, if one works with *pointed* properly convex domains, the analogous space $\mathfrak{C}$ is compact and Hausdorff (J. P. Benzecri's thesis and Goldman's 1990 paper "Convex real projective structures..." are standard sources for this).

So why care about this non-$\text{T}_0$ space rather than its Kolmogorov quotient? Well, it's much more common in practice to care about convex domains than mysterious equivalence classes of convex sets. Sometimes math just gives you lemons and the natural topology on the space you care about isn't $\text{T}_0$.

More significantly, the non-$\text{T}_0$-ness of $\mathfrak{C}$ is a reflection of orbit structure of dynamics of an interesting action of $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$.
It's also the case that geometrically interesting domains have special behavior in $\mathfrak{C}$, which influences their theory.

Let me give an example.
Domains with so much symmetry to admit a cocompact action by $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ ("divisible domains") are closed points of $\mathfrak{C}$ and are of intense interest.
There are many such domains with $C^1$ boundary, with the only such domain with $C^2$ boundary the ellipse.
Any divisible domain in $\mathbb{RP}^2$ with $C^1$ but not $C^2$ boundary contains a dense set of $C^2$ boundary points, all of which have curvature $0$.
The standard proof that any $C^2$ boundary point of a non-ellipse boundary domain has zero curvature uses that divisible domains are closed points in $\mathfrak{C}$.
The sketch is that if $\Omega$ had a $C^2$ boundary point, then using an osculating ellipse and a family of diagonal matricies, one constructs the ellipse in the $\mathfrak{C}$-closure of $\{[\Omega]\}$, which is impossible.
One may similarly prove the fact I mentioned above that the ellipse is the only $C^2$ divisible domain in $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

This is of course only "actually" using the non-$\text{T}_1$ structure of $\mathfrak{C}$.
For objects that witness meaningful non-$\text{T}_0$ structure of $\mathfrak{C}$, certain beautiful (Hitchin) representations of surface groups in $\text{SL}_4(\mathbb{R})$ turn up interesting phenomena.
Such representations $\rho$ preserve domains $\Omega \subset \mathbb{RP}^3$ foliated by peculiar convex domains $\{C_t\}$ $(t \in S^1)$ in copies of $\mathbb{RP}^2$.
It turns out for all except one small class of $\rho$, the families $\{[C_t]\}_{t \in S^1}$ give the only known examples of closed subsets of $\mathfrak{C}$ that are minimal among nonempty closed subsets of $\mathfrak{C}$ but not points, which is a truly-$\text{T}_0$ phenomenon (the source is "Leaves of Foliated..." by me).
One may then deduce similar things about these domains as the above with similar arguments to the divisible case.